# Altova Mapforce XSLT

Tags: xslt, xsd

I have two XSD files from two 3rd party people and an XSLT transform file to transform from one XSD to the other from one of the 3rd parties.

I now need to alter one of the XSD files and the transform file, I've opened both XSD files into Mapforce and I can't for the life of me seem to open the XSLTfile.

I don't know how the XSLT file was originally created and I'm not skilled enough to recreate the whole thing again. Is there anyway I can open the XSLT file in mapforce for it to display all the connections. if not is there a another tool I can get?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally received an email from the support team the current version I'm using (2013 R2) doesn't have back engineering available for XSLT files, so the above isn't possibly.